# Confusion with the definition of a Frechet space regarding completeness and uniqueness of a limit

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I am aware that a Frechet space $V$ is a topological vector space whose topology is induced by countably many seminorms $\{ \lVert \cdot \rVert_k \}$ such that

1. it must be Hausdorff
2. it must be complete

In the [relevant Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space)
it is stated that when constructing a Frechet space, one needs to check that for any sequence $\{ x_n \}$ Cauchy with respect to each seminorm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_k$, there exists some $x \in V$ such that $x_n \to x$ w.r.t. each seminorm.

However, I am quite confused here in that, what if one only finds out that there exists $x^k \in V$ for "each" $\lVert \cdot \rVert_k$ such that $\lVert x_n-x^k \rVert_k \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? That is, there is no guarantee that $x^k = x^{k'}$ for $k \neq k'$.

I tried to resolve this issue by the Hausdroff condition, but cannot find a way out. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the space $X$ of sequences $x=(x_k)_k \in \mathbf{C}^{\mathbf N}$ with finite support, and let $\|x\|_k = |x_k|$. $X$ is clearly not a Fréchet space (one not so elementary reason is that a Fréchet space cannot have countably infinite dimension by Baire's theorem). However, it is easy to see that your condition holds, simply because $\mathbf{C}$ is complete.

Comment: I see, so I must check that condition "independently".